# How do I optimize Hive query with MR engine?

Tags: hadoop, optimization, hive, mapreduce

Got some legacy queries based on jobs that's been running long before I joined the team.   The Hive queries take too long to run and I am on a mission to optimize them.  Before considering Tez, what's are the good parameters that can help query performance? `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize`?

Comment: You should be able to switch to Tez without parameter tuning anything, but you should focus on the storage formats and partitions before tuning other things. Also throwing more memory at YARN containers will work. Otherwise, your question is too broad. We don't know your queries or your data size/types

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007.   Apologies for the vague scenario.   Exploring using ORC file format with Tez.  Data size is really small hence the frustration.   Reviewing the queries to the various joins are optimized and using compression where necessary.

Comment: If the data is less than the HDFS block size (or even less than a few GB), then you should probably be using an actual database, not Hadoop/Hive

Comment: I have indeed moved on to Tez and a 3 hour process now takes 70 minutes.